Why is this part of my for loop not working?
I have this for loop in my code which uses an array filled with randomly generated numbers which is as follow
for (int i = 0; EndResult == true; i++) {   
    count = count + 1;
    
    if (count == 1) {//adds size of arraylist to arraycount
        ArrayCount.add(CardReduce.size());
    }
    
    for (int a = 0; a < CardReduce.size(); a++) {//replaces values by same value - 1
        int val = CardReduce.get(a);
        CardReduce.set(a, (val -1));
    }
    
    for (int b = 0; b < CardReduce.size(); b++) {//removes all elements with value of 0
        CardReduce.remove(Integer.valueOf(0));
    } 
    
    if (count == CardReduce.size()) {//when count is equal to size of CardReduce executes 
        CardReduce.addAll(ArrayCount);
        Collections.sort(CardReduce);
        System.out.println(CardReduce);
        ArrayCount.clear();
        count = 0;
    }
    
    if (count == 8) {
        EndResult = false;
    }
}

my issue is the if loop where count is equal to CardReduce size as all other code except this part works. As this part of the code is supposed to execute once the count is equal to the arraylist size but for some reason it doesn't. As what this for loop is supposed to do is store the size of the original array in a seperate arraylist. And for each cycle loop throught the elements of the randomly generated array subtract one from that number and increase count each time its done remove any zeros if present. Once the count is equal to the size of CardReduce array add the size of the stored array sort that array and clear the stored size so a new one can be added next cycle.
For example lets say the random numbers I got in the array was 2 2 7 9 25 at the end of the first cycle it should now be 1 1 6 8 24 5 but instead I get 4 5 6 22 as the only value of the result that is correct is the 5 as thats the number of elements in the original array but the rest are completely wrong. From testing I pretty sure that the code thats causing the problem is the if loop where count is equal to CardReduce size.
Edit: So this is the code in its entirety but simplified to its necessary parts
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int[] EndResult = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        int[] RandomCards = new int[45];
        int Size = 0;
        int total = 45;
        int count = 0;
    
        for(int i = 0; total > 0; i++) {
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * total) + 1;
            total -= random;
            RandomCards[i] = random;
            Size++;
            Arrays.sort(RandomCards);
            }
        
        System.out.println("Cards Seperated in Stacks: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < RandomCards.length; i++) {
            
            if (RandomCards[i] > 0) {
                System.out.print(RandomCards[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.println("Game Start: ");
        
        ArrayList<Integer> CardReduce = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ArrayCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Boolean FinalResult = true;
        count = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < RandomCards.length; i++) {
            
            if (RandomCards[i] > 0) {
                CardReduce.add(RandomCards[i]);
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; FinalResult == true; i++) {   
            count = count + 1;
            
            if (count == 1) {//adds size of arraylist to arraycount
                ArrayCount.add(CardReduce.size());
            }
            
            for (int a = 0; a < CardReduce.size(); a++) {//replaces values by same value - 1
                int val = CardReduce.get(a);
                CardReduce.set(a, (val -1));
            }
            
            for (int b = 0; b < CardReduce.size(); b++) {//removes all elements with value of 0
                CardReduce.remove(Integer.valueOf(0));
            } 
            
            if (count == CardReduce.size()) {//when count is equal to size of CardReduce executes 
                CardReduce.addAll(ArrayCount);
                Collections.sort(CardReduce);
                System.out.println(CardReduce);
                ArrayCount.clear();
                count = 0;
            }
            
            if (count == 8) {
                FinalResult = false;
            }
        }
    }
}


If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [mre] program, one that condenses your code and your problem into the smallest program possible, small enough to be allowed to be posted in your question as code-formatted text, one that compiles and runs for us without modification, one that demonstrates your problem for us, and also that has no code that is not essential for the above. Please check out the link which explains what this useful tool is and how it can help both you and us.

Running your code through a debugger or even sprinkling a few println statements dumping the contents of your fields would probably show you exactly where you went wrong.

4 5 6 22 is the result after the third iteration of the loop (count = 3) , printed when the if block is indeed executed -- are you aware that deleting the 0 is also changing the size of the list? After the second iteration, the two 2's are reduced to 0 and removed, now CardReduce.size()  has three elements, so on third iteration, count == CardReduce.size()

if you want to see 1 1 6 8 24 5 from the first iteration, you must add/move the println out of the  if block, so it is printed in/after the first iteration

Is this some school assignment? At least give the assignment text :)

The main issue seems to be with removing elements from CardReduce while iterating over it, which can cause some elements to be skipped. To fix this, try using removeIf() after decrementing each element:
for (int a = 0; a < CardReduce.size(); a++) {
    CardReduce.set(a, CardReduce.get(a) - 1);
}
CardReduce.removeIf(val -> val == 0); // removes values that are 0

Also, use originalSize to store the size of CardReduce before modifying it, so the condition count == CardReduce.size() works correctly:
int originalSize = CardReduce.size();
if (count == originalSize) { 
    CardReduce.addAll(ArrayCount);
    Collections.sort(CardReduce);
    ArrayCount.clear();
    count = 0;
}

Lastly, you can use while (FinalResult) instead of for to make the loop condition clearer.
